# ImportError: cannot import name 'render_to_response' from 'django.shortcuts' - Django 3.2 Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djcelery/admin.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
ImportError: cannot import name 'render_to_response' from 'django.shortcuts' (/home/kritik/empereon_django3.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py)
```

I got this when I upgraded Django from 2.2 to 3.2 My python version is 3.8. I am not using **render_to_response** anywhere in my code is it related to python version ? I am not able to understand Can someone help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The render_to_response shortcut was deprecated in Django 2.0, and is removed in Django 3.0. You can use the render shortcut instead, which was added way back in Django 1.3. The render shortcut works similarly to render_to_response, but takes request as its first argument. Change your view as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

Instead of render_to_response

Comment: I have not used render_to_response anywhere in my code.

Comment: check admin.py line 11

Comment: Found the error. There was an issue in django-celery version, I updated that and it resolved the error. Thanks for help.